# How Ethereum nodes are searching for each other?

Tags: addresses

I think it's a pretty silly question, but I'm stuck. If Ethereum (or probably any other *coin) is fully decentralized, how can I find any other nodes without scanning all the network?

I mean, if I know at least one address, I can ask: "Can you tell me any other addresses?". Probably it will send me a list of addresses and I'll ask the same question to each of them, etc. But how can I get the first address? Maybe it's hardcoded or something?

Comment: The bootstrap nodes are  hard-coded.